# Double spelling of url

Tags: html, .htaccess, host

If I write exemple.com, the web address automatically go to exemple.com/exemple.com, but with www.exemple.com, the website work fine,

I tried to redirect to my index, but the problem still persists.

My .htaccess is empty.

Comment: Are you modifying the header in PHP in any way? There must be *some* setting that does this.

Comment: Edit your code with more information. it's unclear.

Comment: my website is html http://tinyurl.com/nfkhesr, i use add domanin, with basical setting, i have more websites on the same host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've stumbled upon this too. Try putting *http://* before the url or just write */* in the a-href.

But you need to supply us with more information and what you want to achieve for us to help you.

Comment: I had descover this site recently, i can give u a bandage, or i don`t know.

I can`t supply you with more information, I don`t know what you need to know.

**Addon domanin** exemple.com
**root**   /public_html/exemple.com
**redirect to***  no redirected 

Ask me and I will provide you more information

Thank you all for helping me

Comment: Best way to redirect to your index is by using your full url to the index, ex. www.example.com/index.html @BuligaVlad